# How to convert an image file to PDF using Wicked PDF?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, wicked-pdf

Right now I am working on Rails 3 version. I want to convert an image file to PDF format. I am using the Wicked PDF gem, but it is not working. Please help me. How to do this?

Comment: And "it is not working" is not a description. We are not mind readers either.

Answer (score 2):

Well from the limited description provided i can give a very rough idea as to what to do.
Wicked PDF comes with a few [helpers](https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf/blob/master/lib/wicked_pdf_helper.rb).

The one you will require is the "wicked_pdf_image_tag". To use this all you have to do is use it as you would use the rails image_tag helper.

```
<%= wicked_pdf_image_tag 'my_image.jpg' %>`
```

Insert the above line into your erb pdf template. But there is a problem with this helper if you have images sitting in places other than the assest/images folder.

If you want to resolve this problem you can go ahead and make a helper of your own, place it in the application helper and you are good to go. For example:

```
 def custom_image_tag(img_name, options={})
 image_tag "file://#{Rails.root}/your/image/location/{img_name}", options
 end
```